# Python : Loop structure occurs error like "list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python, indices

```
uil=[[1], [2], [3, 3, 1], [2, 3], [1], [2]]

for i in uil:

    for j in uil[i]:

        print(uil[i][j])
```

It reports error that: "list indices must be integers, not tuple".

However, it does not work if I add int() to uil[i]. BTW, I hope my code could be simplified by one line and more efficient to process one million tuples.

How can I revise it?

Comment: `for i in uil` iterates over the elements in `uil`, not the indices.  You want `for j in i`.

Answer (score 2):

`i` is not in index, it is *the nested list itself*. Just loop directly over it. Same for `j`:

```
for i in uil:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

The Python `for` statement is really a *for each* construct.

If all you want to do is process each nested value in sequence, with no reference to their grouping into lists, you could just use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to 'flatten' the list:

```
from itertools import chain

for j in chain.from_iterable(uil):
    print(j)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) BTW, have you seen my post that I hope it could be simplified and more efficient to process large quantity of tuples.

Comment: @PythonFun: I did, but you didn't specify what you are *doing* with each tuple.

Answer (score 1):

as martijn said, you are trying to look up a value in a list by passing another list. If you want to keep the indices for some reason, use:

```
uil=[[1], [2], [3, 3, 1], [2, 3], [1], [2]]

for i in range(0,len(uil)):

    for j in range(0,len(uil[i])):

        print(uil[i][j])
```

Comment: No, you'd generally want to use `enumerate()`, so you have both, the original object and an index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) BTW, have you seen my post that I hope it could be simplified and more efficient to process large quantity of tuples.

Comment: what do you want to do with the millions of tuples. If all you want to do is print them then martins answer is great

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised when you try to enter the second loop. In the first loop, `i` is one of the lists from `uil`, converted to a tuple by the `for` loop. As commented, you could use `for j in i:` for the second loop. I recommend doing it this way:

```
for tup in uil:
    for item in tup:
        print(item)
```

Note that I did not name the variables `i` and `j`; those are good when you're looping through a list of integers produced by `range()`, but are confusing when they contain other objects. I think the above code is about as simple as it can get. You probably shouldn't try to print "one million tuples." Python IDLE gets very slow when handling such large output, and I doubt that any shell or IDE would fare much better. Write to a file instead: see the [this Python page](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), section 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `enumerate` -

```
   >>> for i, val in enumerate(uil):
         ...     print i, val
         ... 
       0 [1]
       1 [2]
       2 [3, 3, 1]
       3 [2, 3]
       4 [1]
       5 [2]
```

This prints both the index number and the list. Since, you didnot show your desired output, this might be useful solution. Else, you can use just `print val` to print only the values.